# matlab - find all possible vectors satisfying irregular constraints

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I need to find all possible combinations of a vector that satisfies some constraints that I find quite irregular.

The vector, `x`, has 12 entries: `x_0,x_1,...,x_11`

Local constraints:

```
x_0 in {1,...,6}

x_i in {0,...,6}, i = 1,...,6

x_j in {0,...,12-j}, j = 7,...,11
```

Global constraints:

```
sum(x) = 12

for any k, x_k = y ==> x_{k+j} = 0 for j = 1,...,y-1
```

I have thought about this for quite a while now and can't seem to solve it myself - any ideas anyone?

Comment: Look at optimization: http://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization/

Comment: lakesh do you have any idea and can pinpoint me towards something more specific? I have used matlab for years but this is, in my opinion, more tricky than standard situations

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion and intermediate constraint checking. Something like this does the trick:

```
function dispConstraintSatisfyingVectors()

global lb ub sumVal

lb = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
ub = [6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 4 3 2 1];
sumVal = 12;

x = zeros(1,12);
addValueRecursive(x,1);

end

function addValueRecursive(x,idx)

global lb ub sumVal

for val = lb(idx):ub(idx)
    x(idx) = val;
    if checkZerosConstraint(x) == 0 && sum(x) <= sumVal
        if idx < 12
            addValueRecursive(x,idx+1);
        else
            if sum(x) == sumVal
                disp(num2str(x))
            end
        end
    end
end

end

function c = checkZerosConstraint(x)

c = 0;
for j=1:11
    c = c + sum(x(j+1:j+x(j)-1));
end

end
```